# Is there any way to save my screen layouts across projects?

Tags: customization

I want to save my screen layouts like "Default", "Scripting", "Animation", etc. across projects. Meaning that if I update it one place, it will update across all projects (just like how changing "user preferences" works).

I know I can save a startup .blend with customized layouts. But I work on 2 projects at the same time, thus I need to sync the layouts.

**Edit:** What I need is being able to change the layout in project #1. Then it would update across project #2 and project #3 as well. It doesn't have to simultaneous - it's ok if I need to reopen project #2 and project #3. But I don't wish to change layout in project #1, then make the same changes in the startup-file (thus twice the work).

Answer (score 9):

In User Prefrences > File:
Uncheck `Load UI`

Then, your window layout will be preserved regardless of what file you open.

Comment: That is the layouts you save in your startup.blend file will be used when you don't load the UI.

Comment: This method still requires manually changing the startup file (thus doing the same layout changing twice), then reopening all other projects. It's better than nothing, since it updates all files - but not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 5):

Create a layout that you're happy with and save it using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>**

Now open existing files making sure the **Load UI** is **Unchecked**

[image]

That way the loaded file will use the User Interface/layout you saved as default, and when you re-save the file ,it will save the new UI.